# Change/Update Object Value with TextBox DataBind c#

Tags: c#, data-binding

in my code i have something like that:

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myObject, "id", 
true,System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "0", "N0"));
```

The bind work correctly but when i change the value of textbox my id value doesn't refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me,

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myPlane, "id")
```

And in my class add the interface INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
class Planes : INotifyPropertyChanged
{}
```